# Android Studio not showing configure activity during new project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

[image]

I'm not able to get the configure Activity window, which is resulting every default activity name as MainActivity.java

[image]

Comment: What if you use an uppercase? Or change the language to Kotlin? Funny bug :-)

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can always refactor and rename that activity to whatever you like.

Comment: Just noticed on your screenshot that the application isn't even built properly (i.e. its just showing folders its not referenced as a "package") Try doing "invalidate caches" or if all fails a reinstall of the SDK / AndroidStudioi